# ¿Cómo posicionar elementos en un CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

El layout de mi activity (activity_scrolling.xml) es un `CoordinatorLayout` en el cual hay dos `include` al final (content_scrolling.xml y Activity_tabs.xml).

Lo que quiero es que el activity_tabs se muestre debajo del content_srolling. Lo consigo pero poniendo un `marginTop` a Activity_tabs. Cómo puedo hacerlo sin usar margenes?

**activity_scrolling.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_scroll"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBackdrop_path"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:contentDescription="@string/add_task" />
            
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_task"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accentLightColor"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_task"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accentLightColor"/>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />
    <include layout="@layout/activity_tabs" />
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_scrolling.xml**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvAd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_padding_fab"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/common_padding_min"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/common_padding_min"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOriginalTitleText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin_short"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/titulo_original"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/sub_title"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOriginalTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin_short"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/secondaryLightColor"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvOriginalTitleText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTagLine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin_short"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/accentColor"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvOriginalTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOverview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_padding_default"
                android:text="@string/large_text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTagLine" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btShowmore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Ver más ..."
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvOverview" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/common_padding_none"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btShowmore"
                tools:listitem="@layout/pelis_item" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Activity_tabs.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:textAllCaps="false" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/tabs_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Bien a ver ahora si me explico:
mi intencion es que me muestre en la misma pantalla el activity_scrollin, que tiene la imagen, debajo y tambien desplazable hacia arriba el content_scrollin y debajo tambien desplazable el activity_tabs. El problema es que si en el "LinearLayout" pongo android:layout_height="wrap_content" no me muestra el contenido del <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/nestedScrollView"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">
```

Pero si android:layout_height="Aqui match_partent"

si me muestra como dices correctamente el <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 y claro se pone en pantalla completa, pues ahi esta el error, repito lo que quiero es que se muestre debajo del content_scrollin.
No se como explicarme mejor la verdad, si no me entiendes dejalo, no te molestes mas, perdona las molestias

Comment: Procura que la explicación de  tu problema sea mayor a 2 palabras. "Ordenar includes" no es lo suficientemente claro. Y que significa "no puedo"? Obtienes un error? Cuál es el error? Muestra que resultado obtienes y explica cuál es el resultado esperado.

Comment: @Sinner of the System Ordenar includes creo que es el titulo del problema y "estoy intentando ordenar dos includes uno debajo de otro y no puedo, no se el porque" es la pregunta que viendo el archivo "activity_scrollin.xml" veras que hay dos includes los cuales he de poner un marginTop a Activity_tabs para que se muestre debajo del content_scrolling, como puedo hacer que se muestre debajo del content_scrollin sin ningun marge?

Comment: Ahora está mejor, aunque tampoco te esforzaste mucho. Sólo hay una cosa que no me queda del todo clara.. Cuando dices "que se muestre debajo del content_scrollin" te refieres a que haga scroll junto con el contenido o que esté debajo pero fija (siempre visible)

Comment: Si siempre visible. El content_scrolling se muetra debajo del activity_scrollin pues lo que quiero es que el activity_tabs se muestre debajo del content:_srolling, lo consigo en el tab pero no me muestra el contenido del recyclerView a no ser que le  ponga un marginTop al activity_tabs, lo cual al extender el texto del boton*mas se queda en la misma posicion y se superpone y lo que quiero es que al pulsar el boton mas, el activity_scrolling se desplace tambien hacia abajo. si no me explico bien avisar por favor, no se que hacer para conseguirlo, me esta costando mas de lo que esperaba.*gracias

Comment: No estoy seguro de haber entendido pero escribí una respuesta que puede servirte. Si no es lo que necesitas explica mejor tu problema. Pero en la pregunta no en comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las views que están dentro de un `CoordinatorLayout` pueden usar tres atributos para definir su posición:

- `android:layout_gravity`: ubicación en relación a su contenedor (el coordinatorLayout)
- `app:layout_anchor`: id de la view usada como referencia
- `app:layout_anchorGravity`: ubicación en relación a otra view (la indicada en el atributo anterior)

Si quieres que `Activity_tabs` quede siempre en la parte inferior de la pantalla, la opción más simple es agregarle `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">
```

La otra opción es agregarle un id al elemento root del archivo `content_scrolling` (el NestedScrollView) y usarlo como anchor para colocar a `Activity_tabs` debajo de él

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/content_scrolling" // aquí debe ir el id
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">
```

En cualquier caso deberás eliminar el atributo `app:layout_behavior` y definir la altura como `"wrap_content"` o cualquier valor menor a `match_parent` (este cubriría toda la pantalla)

Comment: Si la altura es "wrap_content" no me muestra el contenido del "androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2" a de ser matcht_parent"

Comment: podrías editar la pregunta y mostrar una imagen de lo que quieres lograr? Si no puedes conseguirlo en tu app, sube una captura de otra que sea similar. Porque como lo explicas ahora es muy difícil de entender

Comment: Ahi esta la captura, espero que lo entiendas

Comment: Correcto Error mio le e dado la altura al wrap_content y correcto, muchas gracias por tu paciencia